# Difference between Google Chrome and Canary

Tags: google-chrome

i would like to know that what is the main difference between chrome and canary
as the official site says,

```
Google Chrome Canary has the newest of the new Chrome features.
Be forewarned: it's designed for developers and early adopters,
and can sometimes break down completely.
```

So what is the good practice:-

1.Can we trust Canary for development purpose.

2.Do we need to test our app on both Canary and Chrome.

3.When we should go for Canary and When we should go for Chrome .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, but make sure that you test the sites with Chrome first when you face a bug. I once had a strange behavior where chars were missing in the sites source and hours later I found out that it was a bug in Canary.
2. I did this for a long time, but I've never stated a problem depending on an update.
3. If you need new functions which aren't currently present in Chrome - use canary. For all other purposes Chrome is the way to go.